# Verificar Webhooks openpay(paypal) -PHP

Tags: php

tengo que verificar un **webhooks** que yo creé y esto me dice **openpay**:

Al terminar la configuración de registro, **Openpay** enviará mediante **POST** un mensaje **JSON** a la **URL** indicada, conteniendo un objeto de notificación **Webhook**. Tu servicio deberá guardar el código de verificación de alguna manera, y regresar el estado 200 OK.

Como puedo obtener el codigo de verificacion en la url que ingrese ?

este es el **json** que me mandara **OpenPay**:

```
{
    "type" : "verification",
    "event_date" : "2013-11-22T11:04:49-06:00",
    "verification_code" : "UY1qqrxw"
}
```

Comment: el webhooks  ya lo creaste? , si es así, podrías detallar mas tu problema ya que no se comprende muy bien cual es tu problema en concreto.

Comment: si. el webhook ya lo hize en el dashboard de openpay. ahi me pide poner una url en donde se verificara y me mandara un el json de ejemplo de arriba. ese codigo lo tengo que recuperar y guardarlo. para lo insertarlo en el dashboard de openpay y se verifique

Comment: Me refería al webhooks que te recibirá la información enviada por openpay

Comment: ¿Recuerdas como resolviste este tema?, me quedé en este punto en la integración

Answer (score -1):

```
$tuResultado = json_decode('Nombre de la variable que recibe el POST');

$verification = $tuResultado->verification_code;
```

Con esto obtienes el codigo de verificación que manda OpenPay.